# execute only after a condition is true

Tags: java, asynchronous, wait, execution

I have a java code that I am pasting below:

```
    package lreal.server;

import fb.datatype.LREAL;
import fb.rt.AbstractEvent;
import fb.rt.EventServer;
import fb.rt.FBRManagementException;
import fb.rt.net.SERVER;
import java.util.*;

public class Double5 {

public SERVER server = new SERVER(0, 1); // creating a server

static LREAL rd1 = new LREAL(); // the variable in which the value received
                                // from client is stored
// it is initialized to zero on declaration.
public double m;



public Double5() {
    // initialize the service / server
    server.QI.value = true;
    server.ID.value = "10.0.0.3:4410";
    server.INIT.serviceEvent(null);

    try {
        // establishing connection to the client.
        server.connectOV("RD_1", rd1);
    } catch (FBRManagementException e1) {
        e1.getMessage();
    }

    // Set up output event handling
    final EventServer initoServer = new AbstractEvent() {
        @Override
        public void serviceEvent(EventServer e) {

            System.out.println("INITO(QO=" + server.QO + ",STATUS= "
                    + server.STATUS + "RD_1= " + rd1);



        }
    };
    server.INITO.connectTo(initoServer);

    server.IND.connectTo(new AbstractEvent() {
        @Override
        public void serviceEvent(EventServer e) {
            initoServer.serviceEvent(e);

            System.out.println("INDICATE(QO=" + server.QO + ",STATUS= "
                    + server.STATUS + "RD_1= " + rd1.value);
            m = rd1.value;


            System.out.println(" value recived inside is " + rd1);

            server.QI.value = false;
            server.INIT.serviceEvent(null);

        }

    });





}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double5 demo1 = new Double5();
    synchronized (demo1) {
        while (demo1.m == 0) {
            try {

                System.out.println(" zero value received");
                demo1.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.getMessage();
            }

        }
        System.out.println(demo1.m);
        demo1.notify();

    }
}
```

}

This is the output I get:

```
 zero value received
INITO(QO=true,STATUS= "OK"RD_1= 45.65
INDICATE(QO=true,STATUS= "OK"RD_1= 45.65
 value recived inside is 45.65
INITO(QO=false,STATUS= "TERMINATED"RD_1= 45.65
```

Essentially what this program does is it creates a server that accepts a value from a client. The received value is stored in an instance rd1 of class LREAL(). After I run this code I initialize the client which is on another software FBDK. The encoding is used to communicate with that software.

So first the initoserver gets executed and then the indserver.

My doubt here is this : I have written a statement as m=rd1.value. value is of type double. When I run this program m gets stored as zero. Whereas it should have the value sent by the client( in this case : 45.65). I want to know if there is way I can block the execution of the print statement after the initializing of the object demo1 in the main method till the value of 45.65 gets stored in m.  I am looking to do it asynchronously. I looked at the wait and notify methods but am not sure if they can be used the way I have in this case, since I want to control execution within the same class. Thank you.

Comment: please properly format your source code and make it as concise as possibe, i.e. remove comments containing deactivated code. this shows you put effort in the question an makes it more likely that you'll receive an answer. As a side note, java convention is to write class names in CamelCase. sticking to a language's conventions makes code more readable to the primary audience, and thus more maintainable.

Comment: Have you **tried** `wait` and `notify` (as opposed to just looking at them)?  Offhand I don't see why it couldn't work, although I'm really not sure what your code does.

Comment: please, as suggested, format the source code properly (for example, if you're in eclipse, press Ctrl+Shift+F). It's still hard to follow the code. Also, now that I can read the code, I noticed that you do not provide program output. That would make it easier to see how your code works, as you have events where we don't know how or when they are triggered.

Comment: Have made the necessary changes. I have been trying to use wait() and notify() for what I am trying to achieve. But still no difference. Would appreciate your opinions and insights. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a while loop just now and it worked. I was able to resolve it. Guess I didnt have to go that deep into synchronizing. Turned out simpler than that. In any case thank you for all your help and insights. Appreciate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double5 demo1 = new Double5();

while (demo1.m==0)
{
System.out.println(" zero value received");
}


System.out.println(" value received is "+ demo1.m);     


}
```